# Finding Maximum Value In A Set

Tags: search, sorting, big-o

If I have a list of numbers where the numbers increase to a point and then decrease after that point, is there a finite number of guesses independent of the size of the set that I would have to make in order to find that maximum value?

The distance between the values is arbitrary and the number of values on the increasing side can be different than the number of values on the decreasing side.

What would be the best method?  Check element 1, then the last element, then the half between?  And repeat?  Or something more sophisticated?

What would the processing time be for such an algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Binary Search comparing two neighboring elements instead of one element to a fixed value. Start at a := 0, b := n, i := (a+b)/2 and compare element(i) to element(i+1). If you notice e(i+1) > e(i), you know the breakpoint is somewhere after i, so set a := i. If e(i) < e(i-1), the opposite is true and you set b := i.

The Complexity would then be O(log n). It would be slightly slower than a regular binary search because you need more comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a rcursive algorithm simmilar to ordered search, based on the number of elements in your list.

Pseudo code:

```
List search(int index, List listpart){
   if(listpart.length()==1){ // already found
       return listpart
   }
   else if(listpart(index+1)>listpart(i) && listpart(index-1)<listpart(i)){ //search right part
      List listpart_tmp = getlistpart(listpart, index, listpart.length())
      return search(index+(listpart.length()/4), listpart_tmp
   }
   else if(listpart(index+1)<listpart(i) && listpart(index-1)>listpart(i)){ //search left part
      List listpart_tmp = getlistpart(listpart, 0, index)
      return search(index-(listpart.length()/4), listpart_tmp
   }
   else if(listpart(index+1)<listpart(i) && listpart(index-1)<listpart(i)){ //found 
      return getlistpart(listpart, index, index)
   }
}
```

The function

```
getlistpart
```

is a function that returns a list consisting of the elements in the original list between the given indices.